# How to use git filter-branch to remove a file by blob SHA1?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

Most of the git filter-branch examples I've seen that are removing files have been to remove files based on *filename*. I don't necessarily want to do that. Instead, I've identified a number of blob (not commit) SHA1s of the files I want to remove, regardless of where they are in the repository. (Due to our repo history, files tend to move around a bunch without changing.)

What's the best way to tell git filter-branch to remove files based on their blob SHA1?

Comment: If you're able to use the BFG repo cleaner, it has simple support for exactly that operation and is much faster than using filter-branch

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your task is to remove blobs from Git history by a hash identifier. You may find it faster and easier to use the BFG rather than `git-filter-branch`, specifically using the `--strip-blobs-with-ids` flag:

> -bi, --strip-blobs-with-ids `<blob-ids-file>`
>     ...strip blobs with the specified Git object ids

Carefully follow the [usage instructions](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage), the core part is just this:

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar  --strip-blobs-with-ids <blob-ids-file>  my-repo.git
```

Note that the `<blob-ids-file>` file should contain Git object ids, rather plain SHA-1 hashes of the blob's contents.

For a given file, you can calculate the Git object id with [`git hash-object`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-hash-object):

```
$ git hash-object README.md
a63b49c2e93788cd71c81015818307c7b70963bf
```

You can see that this value is different to a simple SHA-1 hash:

```
$ sha1sum README.md
7b833f7b37550e2df719b57e8c4994c93a865aa9  README.md
```

...that's because the Git object id hashes a Git header, along with the contents of the file, even though it does use the same SHA-1 algorithm.

The BFG is typically at least 10-50x faster than running `git-filter-branch`, and generally easier to use.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: Something I think isn't mentioned here: by default BFG won't delete from the head commits, right?  So if you want to delete *all* instances of a blob, you have to turn that off...

Comment: That is true, you can disable that with  `--no-blob-protection`. My recommendation with a live code repository would always be to manually fix up your current file tree - and ensure everything still works - before proceeding with a history rewrite. It's much better for me if people don't use my tool to break their production systems! https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#protected-commits

Comment: lol I've noticed your aversion to using `--no-blob-protection`; for what it's worth, since the rewrite is (well, should be) done on a mirror clone anyway, if it breaks we just don't push it back over the original, so no real harm is done

Comment: It might be difficult for a user to realise they've broken something from the mirror clone! If they go straight to pushing the updated mirror back into their main Git repository, that might Continuously Deploy into production or whatever, and they'll only realise the problem then - I'd rather not compound the uncertainty at that stage with the actions of the BFG - better to discover file-dependency problems with simple manual commits that everyone know how to back out of...

Comment: @RobertoTyley It would be great if your tool allowed the user to specify which refs to update instead of blanket-updating all of them.  I want to remove some files for publication to github while keeping an unfiltered copy on a separate branch.  This is annoying to do with your tool.

Comment: @RobertoTyley You say "Carefully follow the usage instructions". But there is no mention at all in the usage instructions about --strip-blobs-with-ids. BFG is a great tool. But I've had to do a lot of searching for details on how to use any of the options.

Answer (score 1):

`git filter branch --index-filter` puts iteratively each commit into the index so it is possible to recover the filename from the hash with `git ls-files -s`.

I do this to remove blobs with hashes 2d341f0223ff, 6a4558fa76d1 and 4d0a90cba061:

`git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git ls-files -cdmo -s | grep ' 2d341f0223ff\| 6a4558fa76d1\| 4d0a90cba061' | awk '{print $4}' | xargs git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch 656565randomstring546464" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`

The random string is to avoid that `git rm` raises an error when `grep` returns no match.

Answer (score 0):

The filter-branch version could look something like this inside of index-filter:

```
git ls-files -s |
  sed -r '/ 02c97746d64fbfe13007a1ab4e9b9e4bbd99f42f /s/^100(644|755)/0/' |
  git update-index --index-info
```

That is, read the index-info format, find the interesting blob and set the mode to 0 (marking it for removal), then write that back to the index.

Comment: Although I'd still recommend using the BFG, I've got to admire this answer for sheer geek chutzpah :heart:

Comment: I believe this would have to be done as a tree filter, making it even slower than the index filter based approach I outlined.  But that's splitting hairs; BFG is the best tool for this job.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @RobertTyley in his answer, you're probably better off using BFG.  However, to answer the question as asked (how to do this with `filter-branch`):

There isn't a great way unfortunately.  You can write a script to get all filenames associated with the SHA value in the index.  As a starting point, if you're removing a file with hash DEADC0DE

```
git rev-list -n 1 --objects HEAD |grep ^DEADC0DE |cut -c 42-
```

You'd then feed each line (perhaps with `xargs`?) as the `<filename>` in

```
git rm --cached <filename>
```

And you'd use that script as your `index-filter` value (because using it as a tree filter will just make an already slow approach even slower).